# Fullcalendar vue component and events as a function

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

i'm playing around with [fullcalendar's vue component](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue)
In detail, i'm trying to load events by using [events (as a function)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)

my code looks like this:

```
 events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                    let start = moment(info.start.valueOf()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    let end = moment(info.end.valueOf()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    axios.get(route('api.apps.fuhrpark2.buchungen'),{
                        params: {
                            start: start,
                            end: end
                        }
                    })
                    .then(response => {                    
                        console.log('event feed success');
                        console.log(response.data);                            
                        successCallback(response.data);
                    }).catch(err =>{
                        console.log('event feed error');
                        console.log(err.response);
                        failureCallback(err);
                    }); 
                }
```

In console i see the fetched data:

```
event feed success
app.js:75467 
[Array(3)]
0: Array(3)
0: {title: "Sebastian (FFHK 2051)", start: "2020-04-02T22:00:00", end: "2020-04-11T07:01:00"}
1: {title: "Sebastian (FFHK 2051)", start: "2020-03-31T08:00:00", end: "2020-03-31T09:00:00"}
2: {title: "Sebastian (FFHK 2052)", start: "2020-03-31T08:00:00", end: "2020-03-31T09:00:00"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

It looks like the data is properly fetched, but no events are rendered. I guess the successCallback(response.data) should initiate the rending, right? But it does not...any hints would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: "I guess the successCallback(response.data) should initiate the rending, right?"...yes it should as long as your events are valid. And it looks like they are, if that printout is accurate. Hard to see what the issue is. Demo (using native fullCalendar): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoqLPGb .

Comment: Do I need to define successCallback and failureCallback using Vue methods?